# Modify source data for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an similar app as in the following example and I can't figure out why the source data is not updating. More info is in the example comments. I'm sure this is some trivial issue that I've overlooked.

**Controller**

```js
    $scope.items = [
        { id: 1, color: 'red', title: 'car' },
        { id: 2, color: 'blue', title: 'sky' },
        { id: 3, color: 'transparent', title: 'nothing' }
    ]
    $scope.favoriteIds = [1, 2, 3]
    $scope.getItem = function(id) { /* returns an item with given id */ }
```

Finally, there are two methods to modify `$scope.items`, but **only the first one works**, because the new item gets *not-already-known* id.

```js
    $scope.changeData1 = function() {
        $scope.items = [{ id: 666, color: 'ugly', title: 'face' }]
        $scope.favoriteIds = [666]
    }

    $scope.changeData2 = function() {
        $scope.items = [{ id: 1, color: 'ugly', title: 'face' }]
        $scope.favoriteIds = [1]
    }
```

**View**

```html
<h1>Favourite items</h1>

<ul ng-repeat="id in favoriteIds" data-ng-init="item = getItem(id)">
    <li>I like my {{ item.color }} {{ item.title }}</li>
</ul>

<button ng-click="changeData1()">Modify data</button>
<!-- prints: I like my ugly face -->

<button ng-click="changeData2()">Modify nothing</button>
<!-- prints: I like my red car -->
```

The problem is, that I need to use this second way to modify data.

http://jsfiddle.net/4pEpN/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm relatively new to Angular as well, so if there's a simple way to do this, I don't know what it is (unfortunately, Angular documentation is atrocious). Regardless, you can avoid this by rethinking the structure of your code (and you'll end up with a better program too).

In your view, you're using `ng-init` to call `getItem` on the `id` during each iteration of your `ng-repeat` loop. This is what's causing your problem, and it's (apparently) due to an Angular performance feature (more at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355122/angularjs-ngrepeat-with-nginit-ngrepeat-doesnt-refresh-rendered-value)).

Basically, don't use `ng-init` except to execute something when your app *starts*. Otherwise, you'll end up with what you've got now: logic in the **view** (calling `getItem(id)`) rather than the **model**, where it belongs.

Instead, use `ng-repeat` to repeat over the *exact* data you want to display. Like I said before, this means some code rearrangement. For example, you could use a function to generate the user's current list of items on the fly. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4pEpN/19/

See my comments in that code for all the changes I made, but the most relevant one is:

```
$scope.favoriteItems = function() {
    var favObjs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < favoriteIds.length; ++i) {
        favObjs.push(getItem(favoriteIds[i]));
    }
    return favObjs;
};
```

then in your view: `<ul ng-repeat="item in favoriteItems()">`

---

There are also lots of other approaches you could use. For instance, you could have an `update` function, which handles anything that might need to be done after any user input (including updating the user's custom array of items). Then you could call this in your `changeData` functions.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I've merged two data collections into single one and then just iterated over it. It started to cause a minor problem because the generate function (like `favoriteItems()` in this example) was called many times for every single data change. Fortunately, this can be handled properly with the `$scope.$watch`, so I left the `favoriteItems` to be an array and used `$watch` to fire update events.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `ng-init` is appropriate since it only affects template initialization.
So how about just calling your `getItem(id)` for fetching each attribute, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/JrvbD/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I agree with inappropriate use of `ng-init`. Unfortunately, in a real app the template is much complex than this example, so calling `getItem(id)` many times wouldn't be great for performance.

Comment: Hmm, I would have suggested the correct way to do this without the repeated calls would be adding a filter based on favoriteIds in the ng-repeat's expression. But in testing it looks like angular treats the filter as static and is really only watching the input to it. You can see the /2/ of my last jsfiddle, but try commenting out the change to items and you'll see it isn't really watching the filter.